# Finding a pair of row in SQL

Tags: sql

I am very confused how to define the problem statement but Let's say below is table History i want to find those rows which have a pair.

Pair I will defined like column a and b will have same value and c should have False and d should be different for both row.

If I am using Java i would have set row 3, C column as true when i hit a pair or would have saved both row 1 and row 3 into different list. So that row 2 can be excluded. But i don't know how to do the same functionality in SQL.

```
Table - History 

col a, b, c(Boolean ), d
    1  bb F            d          
    1  bb F            d
    1  bb F            c

Query ? ---- 
Result - rows 1 and 3.
```

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) structure(create table) and data(insert) please.

Comment: Thank you but we don't have any ID.

Comment: Are you allowed to add one?

Comment: Updated the answer with added PK.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table is called `test`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    test
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT
        MIN(id)
    FROM
        test
    WHERE
        !c
        AND a = b
        AND d != a
    GROUP BY a, d
)
```

We get the smallest `id` of every where matching your conditions. Furthermore we group the results by `a, d` which means we get only unique pairs of "a and d". Then we use this ids to select the rows we want.

Working [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2PwenZfuw8i34VhBor2sSS/4).

### Update: without existing id

```
# add PK afterwards
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

Working [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2PwenZfuw8i34VhBor2sSS/6).

Comment: Thanks Bro but Table has no key as such.

Comment: @AT Thats why i added the `ALTER TABLE...` so you can add one.

Answer (score 0):

All the rows match the conditioin you specified. A "pair" happens when:

- column a and b will have same value, and
- c should have False, and
- d should be different for both rows.

`1` and `3` will match that as well as `2` and `3`. Also, `3` and `1` will match as well as `3` and `2`. There are four solutions.

You don't say which database, so I'll assume PostgreSQL. The query that can search using your criteria is:

```
select *
from t x
where exists (
  select null from t y 
  where y.a = x.a
    and y.b = x.b
    and not y.c
    and y.d <> x.d
);
```

Result:

```
a  b   c      d 
-- --- ------ - 
1  bb  false  d 
1  bb  false  d 
1  bb  false  c
```

That is... the whole table.

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sWJXTGe3WsqyDTWiAGR1GP/0).

Comment: Row 1 already paired wit row 3. so it can't be paired with row 2. Same for row 3 it is paired with row 1 identical to row 2. So it can not be paired again.

Comment: @AT Well... that's an extra condition you didn't mention in the question. Please ask a new question if needed.